# Изменения в таблице после второго нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть задача которая требует заменить текст в таблице (не важно какой) после второго нажатия на кнопку. Например нажав на кнопку второй раз, значение второй строки таблицы Audi изменится на BMW.

```js
//Код добавления массива в таблицу:

function arraytotable(){
var array = [
["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"]]

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
// create a new row
var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
{
// create a new cell
var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

// add value to the cell
cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
}
}
}
arraytotable()
//Задачу начал выполнять написав код для подсчёта нажатий на кнопку:
var cnt=-1;
function onButtonClick(){
     cnt+=1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>1 Laboratorinis darbas </h1>
<table id="myTable">
  <caption id=a><strong>Automobiliai</caption></strong>
  <tr>
    <th>Modelis</th>
    <th>Gamintojas</th>
    <th>Metai</th>
    <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="test" onclick="pavadinimas(); onButtonClick">Mygtukas</button>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField(this);" />
</body>
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как мне из этой функции обратиться к таблице, чтобы изменить в ней любое значение.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt = -1;
function onButtonClick() {
  cnt += 1;
  if (cnt == 1) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: это я понял, но в таком случае если вывести результат в консоль, то в результате я получаю всю структуру таблицы. не понимаю как добраться до данных в таблице)

Comment: @Dimensijus Это не то что Вы написали в вопросе. На то что Вы написали в вопросе, я уже ответил.